# Add font awesome icons to a form label

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, font-awesome

Is it possible to use font awesome icons within a label when creating a form for example.

if my form looks like this

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
```

How would i add the i class to the label?

I have tried this

```
<%= f.label :email, :class => 'icon-user' %>
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
```

but this doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this (assuming `email` is a field of class `User`):

```
<%= f.label :email do %>
  <i class="icon-user"></i>
  <%= User.human_attribute_name :email %>
<%- end -%>
```